# Get post_meta from specific post

Tags: post-meta

I'm trying to get the post_meta from a specific post.
However: the following code breaks my document:

```
    $img= get_post_meta('4996','ATHLETE-side_img';
```

Then further down in the code I was planning to use $img as an img source.

Any help?

Comment: you are missing the closing `)`. Should be `$img = get_post_meta( '4996', 'ATHLETE-side_img' );`.

Comment: @Abhik now my page isn't broken, but echo "<img src='" . $img . "'/> still doesn't display the image, any suggestions?

Comment: I get img src "Array"

Comment: in postmeta table your meta is same as "ATHLETE-side_img" or it is different like "_ATHLETE-side_img" ?

Comment: This should work: `$img = get_post_meta( '4996', 'ATHLETE-side_img', true );`

Comment: That works @Abhik thanks for your help!
One more question: how would I insert the entire get_post_meta line inside an echo? echo "<img src='" . get_post_meta( '4996', 'ATHLETE-side_img', true ); . "'/>; is failing me

Comment: If you're concatenating a string, remove the semicolon - `true ); . "`

Comment: That's because you are closing the line with `;` (semicolon). Remove that and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis, but you also need to [set `$single` to `true`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), otherwise the function will return an array of meta entries for the key (even if there is only one):

```
get_post_meta( 4996,'ATHLETE-side_img', true /* $single */ );
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also what Abhik just found, thanks for your time!

Comment: Please mark it as a valid answer, anyway, so other users might find it and understand that it works.